# Created a custom directive for tabs. On click of Next Button need to go to the next tab, and on click of back button need to come to previous tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My **Main.Html** which contains the tab directives.

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <span class="modal-title">Add Report Template</span>
  <div class="closeButton right" ng-click="closeModal()"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <tab-set>
    <tab heading="1st Tab">
      This is the content for 1st Tab     
    </tab>
    <tab heading="2nd Tab">
      This is the content for 2nd tab
    </tab>
    <tab heading="3rd Tab">
      This is the content for 3rd tab.
    </tab>
  </tab-set>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div>
    <button type="text" class="grayButton right" ng-click="goToNextTab()">Next</button>
    <button type="text" class="grayButton left" ng-click="goToPreviousTab()">Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My **Main.controller** where i need the define the function for Next and Back Button

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope,) {
            var vm = this;
            /////////////// Function to Change tab on click of the Back/Next Button ///////////////
            $scope.goToNextTab = function() {
                
            };
            
            $scope.goToPreviousTab = function() {
            
            };
        }]);
})();
```

My **TabSet directive** that displays the 3 tabs.

```
    angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('TabSet', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {   },
            templateUrl: 'tabset.html',
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: 'tabs',
            controller: function($scope) {
                var self = this;
                self.tabs = [];
                self.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
                    self.tabs.push(tab);
                    if(self.tabs.length === 1) {
                        tab.active = true;
                    }
                };
                self.select = function(selectedTab) {
                    angular.forEach(self.tabs, function(tab) {
                        if(tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
                            tab.active = false;
                        }
                    });
                    selectedTab.active = true;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

**Tabset Html** for the corresponding **tabset directive**.

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tabsets">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="tab in tabs.tabs" ng-class="{'active': tab.active}">
      <a href="#{{tab.heading}}" role="tab" ng-click="tabs.select(tab)">{{tab.heading}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

This is the **Tab directive** for creating the individual tabs.

```
 angular
        .module('myApp')
        .directive('Tab', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                template: `<div role="tabpanel" ng-show="active"><div ng-transclude></div></div>`,
                require: '^TabSet',
                scope: {
                    heading: '@'
                },
                link: function(scope, elem, attr, tabs) {
                    scope.active = false;
                    tabs.addTab(scope);
                }
            }
        });
```

I am not too sure what I am missing, but for the given structure I want to switch tabs based on click of the Next as well as Back Button defined in main.html.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @NaguibIhab i dont have a fiddle for it, just tried to give you the skeleton of my code running on production. Can you kindly try creating at your end?

Comment: @NaguibIhab https://thinkster.io/angular-tabs-directive you can refer this link for a local setup. But just remember to add the two buttons in the Main.html.

Answer (score -1):

I see your code is wrong on link function of Tab directive.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, reporttabs) {
    scope.active = false;
    tabs.addTab(scope);
}
```

You need to change tabs.addTab to reporttabs.addTab

And here is the solution for the feature you want to implement. You need to add a selectedTabIndex property into scope of Tabset. So you can use scope.$watch function and when the selectedTabIndex has changed you can call scope.select(selectedTab). Here code example:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope,) {
        var vm = this; vm.selectedTabIndex = 0;
        $scope.goToNextTab = function() {
          vm.selectedTabIndex += 1;
        };

        $scope.goToPreviousTab = function() {
          vm.selectedTabIndex -= 1;
        };
    }]);
angular
.module('myApp')
.directive('TabSet', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { 'selectedTabIdex': '=' },
        templateUrl: 'tabset.html',
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'tabs',
        controller: function($scope) {
            var self = this;
            self.tabs = [];
            self.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
                self.tabs.push(tab);
                if(self.tabs.length === 1) {
                    tab.active = true;
                }
            };
            self.select = function(selectedTab) {
                angular.forEach(self.tabs, function(tab) {
                    if(tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
                        tab.active = false;
                    }
                });
                selectedTab.active = true;
            };
            $scope.$wacth('selectedTabIndex', function(newValue, oldValue) {
              var index = newValue;
              if(index >= self.tabs.length) {
                return $scope.selectedTabIndex = 0;
              }
              if(index < 0) {
                return $scope.selectedTabIndex = self.tabs.length - 1;
              }
              self.select(self.tabs[index]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: sorry about that. I have edited the question for the first point you mentioned.

Comment: I am getting a console error. "Cannot set property 'active' of undefined", on line "selectedTab.active = true;" AND ALSO on line "self.select(self.tabs[index]);" .